# Get suggest simple_phrase query values returns "undefined"

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch

How to get suggested query values from elasticsearch nodejs client.

I have such kind of index named **test** :

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "trigram": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase","shingle"]
          },
          "reverse": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase","reverse"]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "word": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "trigram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "trigram"
          },
          "reverse": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "reverse"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and want to take ***suggest.simple_phrase*** values by the help of elasticsearch client by this way:

```
getElasticSearchResult: (_, params, context) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const param: RequestParams.Search = {
          index: 'test',
          body: {
            suggest: {
              text: 'params.searchText',
              simple_phrase: {
                phrase: {
                  field: 'word.trigram',
                  size: 1,
                  gram_size: 3,
                  direct_generator: [
                    {
                      field: 'word.trigram',
                      suggest_mode: 'always',
                    },
                  ],
                  highlight: {
                    pre_tag: '<em>',
                    post_tag: '</em>',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        };
        client
          .search(param)
          .then((result: ApiResponse) => {
            resolve(result.body.suggest.simple_phrase);
            console.log('---- ', resolve(result.body));
            // keep results in array (allRecords)
          })
          .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          });
      }).then(v => {
        return allRecords;
      }),
},
```

but result.body is undefined and why?

request comes correctly and result structure is also correct but inside everything is empty.

Comment: Can you try checking what you is returned in request object?

Comment: do you mean RequestParams object?

Comment: I'm talking about request object in this line resolve(result.body.suggest.simple_phrase)

Comment: it's empty, just undefined